# Некорректное удаление строки по ее номеру в openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

пытаюсь удалить выбранные строки по их номерам, некоторые строки не удаляются, а некоторые столбцы начинают смещаться

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
rowsList = [1,3,5,6,8,10]
wb = load_workbook('путь к файлу.xlsx')
currentSheet = wb.worksheets[0]
for i in rowsList:
    currentSheet.delete_rows(i)
wb.save('путь к файлу.xlsx')
```

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло!

Comment: примите тогда ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы удаление произошло коррекно, нужно использовать `reversed(rowsList)`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

rowsList = [1,3,5,6,8,10]
wb = load_workbook('путь к файлу.xlsx')
currentSheet = wb.worksheets[0]

for i in reversed(rowsList):
    currentSheet.delete_rows(i)
wb.save('путь к файлу.xlsx')
```